# how to solve file can not be created error code 3 in vs code while set up vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

[this pop up when I setup vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2lpO.jpg)
some days back i copied vs code from its default location of c drive to e drive while watching some random video on youtube to save c drive space but i think i messed up but also before doing that i created restore point with the name vs_code but i run that today but it did not work and it say that no changes made and i try this lot of time but it just didn't work...please help

please help so that i can use vs code